# Universal Image Loader resizing not working as expected?

Tags: android

So far I think the UIL api is by far the best!  The fact that there is extensive JavaDoc and source code to hand is a real credit to the developer who has made this available.  The reason for my post is that I am having trouble with the generated image size not matching what I have requested.  The knock on is that the view where I want to put the generated bitmap blows up in size relative to the place holder thumbnail that was in the ImageView.

I have extended ImageViewAware as follows so that I can use the intrinsic height and width of the Drawable currently contained in the ImageView rather than the ImageView dimensions themselves which are both set to 'wrap_content'.

The intrinsic width and height are returning as 78 * 78, but even though I provide these sizes to UIL the returned generated bitmap is sized at 153 * 204?

```
package com.android.eyespy.helper;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.imageaware.ImageViewAware;

public class ImageViewDrawableAware extends ImageViewAware {

    public ImageViewDrawableAware(ImageView imageView) {
        super(imageView);
    }

    @Override
    public int getWidth() {
        Drawable drawable = imageViewRef.get().getDrawable();
        return drawable!=null ? drawable.getIntrinsicWidth() : super.getWidth();
    }

    @Override
    public int getHeight() {
        Drawable drawable = imageViewRef.get().getDrawable();
        return drawable!=null ? drawable.getIntrinsicHeight() : super.getHeight();
    }

    public boolean setImageBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
        ImageView imageView = imageViewRef.get();
        int viewWidth = imageView.getDrawable().getIntrinsicWidth();
        int viewHeight = imageView.getDrawable().getIntrinsicHeight();

        int bitmapWidth = bitmap.getWidth();
        int bitmapHeight = bitmap.getHeight();

        return super.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }
}
```

Anyone have any ideas why the generated bitmap dimensions are not matching what I expect?

The configuration I am using to setup ImageLoader on application start are below too

```
DisplayImageOptions defaultOptions = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
.cacheOnDisc(true)
.considerExifParams(true)
.build();        

ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(getApplicationContext())
.defaultDisplayImageOptions(defaultOptions)
.build();

ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config);
```

Thanks